# Wordpress images not displaying in front on xampp local server

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend

I have configured my live website code in local XMPP server. But I have not seen images on the frontend. Below link image has broken.
http://localshot/teachertalking/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/tab1.png

Answer (score 0):

No one have access to Your localhost :-) Try to change chmod for files.

Comment: How to change chmod in localhost?

Comment: I don't know what system You have, if Windows - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX2WsUfW_x4 , if OS X , just click right button on folder, choose informations and set read and save for all users.